# Java incompatible types inference error when refactored

Tags: java, generics

I'm writing a method that's converting a collection into a sorted map-of-maps using two levels of grouping. The code works correctly, but when I try pulling the map supplier out into its own method, IntelliJ/Java breaks type inference and the code doesn't compile.

Original code:

```java
collection.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    item -> item.getKey(),
    () -> new TreeMap<>(keyComparator),
    Collectors.groupingBy(
      secondItem -> secondItem.getKey(),
      () -> new TreeMap<>(secondKeyComparator),
      Collectors.toList()
    )
  );
```

Refactored code:

```java
collection.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    item -> item.getKey(),
    sortedMapBuilder(keyComparator),
    Collectors.groupingBy(
      secondItem -> secondItem.getKey(),
      sortedMapBuilder(secondKeyComparator),
      Collectors.toList()
    )
  );

...

private <K, V> Supplier<TreeMap<K, V>> sortedMapBuilder(Comparator<K> comparator) {
  return () -> new TreeMap<>(comparator);
}
```

What am I missing that's preventing Java from inferring the correct generic types in the refactored example?

I get two different errors depending on how I move the code around:

```
Error:(95, 25) java: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.util.TreeMap<java.lang.String,java.util.TreeMap<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>>>,M
    upper bounds: java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.TreeMap<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>>>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>>>,java.lang.Object

Error:(109, 37) java: incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
    inferred: java.util.TreeMap<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>>
    equality constraints(s): java.util.TreeMap<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.String>>
```

Comment: What is `collection`?

Comment: It can be any `java.util.Collection` (I'm using a Set, but it shouldn't matter if you used List for example).

Comment: Post the specific error message.

Comment: Can you post code that compiles? I suspect the fix is something simple, such as changing `Comparator<K>` to `Comparator<? super K>`